# Consistency handling in gateway aggregation?

Tags: microservices

We have a scenario which is candidate for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/gateway-aggregation . But we have an additional complexity that this aggregation should implement consistency among these service calls. Is it a good pattern to implement a saga in the gateway

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more ? What i understand is that you want to aggregate the response from different services but you have to be sure they are all consistent when you are aggregating the response ?

Comment: These requests are not data fetching requests but data modifying requests. We need to implements an eventual consistency model among these services for this particular business flow. If we call a single service and it triggers event which create another series of service changes then we should have implement a saga in that service. Reason for going for gateway aggregation is that these services need different data but still we have the same requirement on data consistency